# WhatsApp with UIActivityViewController for sharing image not using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, ios7, whatsapp

How to set up **WhatsApp** with `UIActivityViewController` for sharing image, not using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Please let me know if there is another way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This is the code to share ***text and url*** from activity controller

```
NSString *URLString=@"http://video.app.com/video.php?";

NSURL *VideoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

NSMutableArray *activityItems= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:VideoURL, @"Hey, check out this video I've shared with you, it's awesome!", nil];

self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
self.activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                      UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                      UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                      UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                                      UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**For Swift 3.0**

```
let objectsToShare = ["\(Title) \n \(Description)"]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.setValue("App Name", forKey: "subject")

let excludeActivities = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.postToWeibo]
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities

self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

Comment: @iOS_Raj is know its late but saw your question and replied with answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the URL scheme approach described here on the official WhatsApp site:

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013

Comment: Actually i have created custom UIActivity For WhatsApp i can share text easy, but not image i have to use UIDocumentInteractionController  in UIActivityController, but its not working, is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, I never tried this myself so I don't have an easy answer.